# Google Places Library Replacement for google.maps.LocalSearch()

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-local-search

Now that the Google Local Search API has been deprecated, is there a functional equivalent of  `google.maps.LocalSearch()` in the Google Maps JavaScript Places Library? Specifically, I have a map on my website and within the map I placed a LocalSearch text-edit box with the following line:

```
   a_map.addControl(new google.maps.LocalSearch(),
   new GControlPosition(G_ANCHOR_BOTTOM_RIGHT, new GSize(10,20)));
```

The user could then enter search text and a list of hits would appear above the text-edit box. How can I achieve the same result (or close) with the new Places library?

Thanks.

Comment: If there is no equivalent for LocalSearch and input has to be handled elsewhere on the webpage, say a form input field, that would suffice as an answer. I'm just not sure that's the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for [Places API Autocomplete](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/autocomplete).  [Here's a nice live demo](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete).